# AngularJS bindings delayed when code is inside SignalR callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, signalr

I have some code that updates AngularJS $scope properties. If this code is run in a function, the web page is updated immediately. However, that same code, when running inside the SignalR callback function, won't immediately update the web page.

Code that causes the bindings to update immediately:

HTML with Angular bindings:

```
<input id="name" type="text" ng-model="playerName" /><button ng-click="RegisterPlayer();">Register</button>
```

Function within Angular controller:

```
  $scope.RegisterPlayer = function () {

      $scope.numberOfPlayers += 1;
      var player = {
          name: $scope.playerName,
          randomNumber: 0,
          totalScore: 0
      }
      $scope.players.push(player);
  }
```

When this runs, the number of players is immediately upated on the web page.

Here is how I refactored the code to send the info to a SignalR hub, and then use that same code within the SignalR callback:

Here is the same function as above, but now it just sends the info to a SignalR hub:

```
  $scope.RegisterPlayer = function () {

      hub.server.send($scope.playerName, -1);
  }
```

And this is the code within the callback (it does get hit, so the wiring is correctly done):

```
  function receiveSignalRMessage(name, message) {
      var randomNumber = parseInt(message, 10);

      // -1 means the player was registered
      if (randomNumber == -1) {
          $scope.numberOfPlayers += 1;
          var player = {
              name: $scope.playerName,
              randomNumber: 0,
              totalScore: 0
          }
          $scope.players.push(player);
          return;
      }
  }
```

This actually works, except that the web page doesn't update the bindings until the next time a button is clicked on the page. It's the same code as before, but now it's just inside the callback. Why wouldn't my page update immediately?

Comment: I think you may neeed to wrap your code in a `$scope.apply` block:  http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

Comment: That did it! That article was a great explanation. If you'd like to post your comment as an answer, I'll accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular won't automatically notice changes to scope if they occur during 'external' callbacks.

In cases like these you need to tell angular that the scope has changed yourself, and you do this by wrapping your code in a `$scope.apply` block:

There is a good explanation here: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html